# Why my images do not appears in a modal? Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter to develop a web system and I have to add a carousel slide on a modal, but the images does not appears when I'm using a foreach to select an image one by one

I'm running this web system with codeigniter 3.2 and php 7. I'm using a theme from themeforest called 'Pages ADM' which uses owl-carousel plugin.

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <?php foreach ($produto['midias'] AS $midia) :?>     
     <img src="<?=base_url('uploads/midias/').$midia;?>"/>          
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in my controller

```
$data['produto'] = $produto;
$data['produto']['midias'] = $this->produto_midia_class->listar('*');
```

where the function 'listar' was defined in my model

When Im using local images they appears, but when I'm using foreach, these images do not appear.

Comment: So what does the resulting HTML look like when you look at the `page source`

Comment: Make sure that your server can handle `<?=` as short hand for `echo`. Otherwise try `<?php echo base_url('uploads/midias/').$midia;?>`

Comment: Check the html source code generated by the foreach and compare it with the one that works. What differences do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to concatenate the string afterwards. Within "" the variables will be output.

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url()."uploads/midias/$midia";?>">
```

You could also do something like this:

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <?php 
        foreach ($produto['midias'] as $midia){
            $baseurl = base_url();
            echo "<img src='$baseurl"."uploads/midias/$midia'>";
        }    
     ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also just to note that usually the $midia will need an identifier like the column name if pulled from a database such as

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <?php 
        foreach ($produto['midias'] as $midia){
            $baseurl = base_url();
            $imageurl = $midia->url;
            echo "<img src='$baseurl"."uploads/midias/$imageurl'>";
        }    
     ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry about the long time, but yeah its finally works! thx buddy